# Using java.time.LocalDate in a field with Jasper Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have an application developed in NetBeans 8.1 with iReport and JasperReport version 5.5.0 plugin. In my application, I have a jasper report with a `JRBeanCollectionDataSource`.

```
LocalDate dateFrom = jDateChooser1.getDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
LocalDate dateUntil = jDateChooser2.getDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
List<Registru> regs = db.getRegistreFrom(dateFrom, dateUntil);

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
String absolutePath = "....\\rapoarte\\";
params.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", absolutePath);
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/rapoarte/registreListare.jasper");
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(in, params, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(regs,false));

// ... code here
```

`JRBeanCollectionDataSource` takes a parameter of List of Report class returned from the database

```
public class Registru {
   private int id;
   private int nrReg;
   private LocalDate date;
   // ... getters and setters
}
```

The problem is that in the report the fields are :

```xml
<field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="nrReg" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="date" class="java.time.LocalDate"/>
```

but when I compile it, it gives me an error

> java.time.LocalDate cannot be resolved to a type

It works only if I put `<field name="date class="java.lang.Object"/>` but I cannot format the date.

I want to format the date of pattern `"dd-MM-yyyy"`.
Do I have to add something to the jasper's classpath?

Comment: I gave up to use jasper reports plugin in netbeans and I started to use JasperStudio to create and compile jrxml files . But It was easyear to work with all files under NetBeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is related to the **JTD compiler** (compiler for the jrxml) that you are using.

You will need a recent version of Eclipse Java Compilers (ecj) to use java-8, check the [jasper-distribution](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library).

To use pattern on the `java.time.LocalDate` or `java.time.LocalDateTime` see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38830722/5292302) for more information

Comment: I'm using Netbeans 8.1 with following plugins :  iReport-5.5.0.nbm, jasperserver-plugin-5.5.0.nbm , jasperreports-components-plugin-5.5.0.nbm. How can I change the Java Compiler? Thanks

Comment: Check what JDT compiler you are using currently search for ecj or Jdt-compiler, basically remove old one from class path and set new one ejc to classpath. However my advice is to not use plugins (I use iReport installed or JasperSoft Studio) to avoid plugin problems.

Comment: Just to complement http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/844403/how-run-jasperreports-java-8