# How to format java.time.LocalDate in a textField?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, java-time

I am trying to display a `java.time.LocalDate` in my report with the format :

```
<textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
    <reportElement x="64" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="5e003c53-2327-4f75-9adf-831a3bb494ff"/>
    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
        <font isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dateFacture}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

But I am getting a date like : 2017-03-09.   Is it due to the type java.time.LocalDate?

Comment: It looks like the result from `LocalDate.toString()` alright. I don’t know the Jasper Reports answer to this question. In pure Java you would use `LocalDate.format(DateTimeFormatter)`.

Comment: Solved : $F{dateFacture}.format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE d MMMM yyyy"))

Comment: @PetterFriberg, the answers to that other question explain how to format a `LocalDateTime` in Java — not a `LocalDate` in a Jasper report. The question is tagged jasper-reports, not java, it may mean that the Jasper report context was the issue for the asker? thomas can best tell.

Comment: I have enhanced this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830722/how-to-format-java-time-localdatetime-with-pattern) to include `java.time.LocalDate` and it shows how to do it with pattern that seems to be the initial intention of OP. Note in jasper-reports it's also better to use pattern to have correct format in export to for example excel.

Answer (score 4):

Just to document that this question has been answered, here’s the solution that the asker reported in a comment:

```
<textFieldExpression>
    <![CDATA[$F{dateFacture}.format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.of‌​Pattern("EEEE d MMMM yyyy"))]]>
</textFieldExpression>
```